# SQL: Using COUNT(*) Instead of EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to use COUNT in place of EXISTS?

I have following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Goals G
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM tfv_home_last6(G.Date, G.Home) WHERE GameNumber <= 6 AND     
HomeGoals >= 3)
```

Instead of returning the row if at least one row exists in the subquery, I'd like to specify a number of rows that need to be returned in the subquery, something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM Goals G
WHERE ROWCOUNT(*) >= 2 (SELECT NULL FROM tfv_home_last6(G.Date, G.Home) WHERE GameNumber <= 6 AND     
HomeGoals >= 3)
```

I'm not sure how to go about it?

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: It is *possible* - but not **recommended** - why? Imagine a table with 10 million rows; if you use `COUNT(*) > 0`, then the query must run over the ***entire 10 million rows*** to count the occurrences of your value and return that count. On the other hand, if you use `IF EXISTS()`, the query can **stop** as soon as the first occurrence has been met. So yes - *you can* but you **should not**

Comment: @marc_s - that's a good caveat but it might still be the best choice.

Comment: @Greg: definitely ***not*** on a large table! (> 1 million rows)

Comment: @marc_s - OP didn't mention a large table, which is why I said it's a caveat.

Comment: @marc_s: how about using `top x` in the subquery?

Comment: @YK: if you have a good index supporting the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses of the subquery, and you're not selecting `TOP (9999999) ....` - then yes, that might work. With an index and a sufficiently small number, you'll get back just that number of rows

Comment: I'm not using a large table so not too worried about performance, I just want it to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the subquery pretty much just like you describe:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Goals G
WHERE (SELECT count(*)
       FROM tfv_home_last6(G.Date, G.Home)
       WHERE GameNumber <= 6 AND HomeGoals >= 3
      ) > 0;
```

However, this requires calculating the entire count.  The `exists` form is more efficient, because it stops at the first matching record.

In SQL Server 2012, you could also use `cross apply:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Goals G cross apply
     (select count(*) as cnt
      FROM tfv_home_last6(G.Date, G.Home)
      WHERE GameNumber <= 6 AND HomeGoals >= 3
     ) a
WHERE a.cnt > 0;
```

I do not know which would have better performance, the correlated subquery in the `where` clause or the 
cross apply version.

Comment: If a subquery is in the `where` clause wouldnt it run for every row? compared to a subquery in your `from` clause that would only run once?

Comment: @JafarKofahi . . . Well, yes.  It is a correlated subquery so it would have to run for every row, in order to get the right rows.  The `cross apply` will do the same thing.  Don't confuse running the subquery with running the subquery on *all* the data.  In both cases, it will run the subquery using the values from one row of `Goals`.

Comment: When it's in the `WHERE` clause, would it run the subquery separately for each row (like a stored procedure), or would the optimizer basically convert this to a `JOIN`?

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff - This has done the trick, thanks. I tried them both and there doesn't seem to be a difference in performance so I'm going with the first one.